# How can I optimize this query with multiple joins?

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I'm using PostgreSQL 14.1. My query looks like this:

```
SELECT stats_game.id AS stats_game_id,
       stats_fighters.left_fighter AS stats_fighters_left_fighter,
       stats_fighters.right_fighter AS stats_fighters_right_fighter,
       stats_timestamp.ts AS stats_timestamp_ts,
       stats_timestamp.time_of_day AS stats_timestamp_time_of_day,
       stats_coefs.wl AS stats_coefs_wl,
       stats_coefs.wr AS stats_coefs_wr,
       stats_coefs.wlr AS stats_coefs_wlr,
       stats_coefs.wrr AS stats_coefs_wrr,
       stats_coefs.f AS stats_coefs_f,
       stats_coefs.b AS stats_coefs_b,
       stats_coefs.r AS stats_coefs_r,
       stats_coefs.flaw AS stats_coefs_flaw,
       stats_rounds.one AS stats_rounds_one,
       stats_rounds.two AS stats_rounds_two,
       stats_rounds.three AS stats_rounds_three,
       stats_rounds.four AS stats_rounds_four,
       stats_rounds.five AS stats_rounds_five,
       stats_rounds.six AS stats_rounds_six,
       stats_rounds.seven AS stats_rounds_seven,
       stats_rounds.eight AS stats_rounds_eight,
       stats_rounds.nine AS stats_rounds_nine,
       stats_roundsview.one_view AS stats_roundsview_one_view,
       stats_roundsview.two_view AS stats_roundsview_two_view,
       stats_roundsview.three_view AS stats_roundsview_three_view,
       stats_roundsview.four_view AS stats_roundsview_four_view,
       stats_roundsview.five_view AS stats_roundsview_five_view,
       stats_roundsview.six_view AS stats_roundsview_six_view,
       stats_roundsview.seven_view AS stats_roundsview_seven_view,
       stats_roundsview.eight_view AS stats_roundsview_eight_view,
       stats_roundsview.nine_view AS stats_roundsview_nine_view,
       stats_roundsviewfinish.one_view_f AS stats_roundsviewfinish_one_view_f,
       stats_roundsviewfinish.two_view_f AS stats_roundsviewfinish_two_view_f,
       stats_roundsviewfinish.three_view_f AS stats_roundsviewfinish_three_view_f,
       stats_roundsviewfinish.four_view_f AS stats_roundsviewfinish_four_view_f,
       stats_roundsviewfinish.five_view_f AS stats_roundsviewfinish_five_view_f,
       stats_roundsviewfinish.six_view_f AS stats_roundsviewfinish_six_view_f,
       stats_roundsviewfinish.seven_view_f AS stats_roundsviewfinish_seven_view_f,
       stats_roundsviewfinish.eight_view_f AS stats_roundsviewfinish_eight_view_f,
       stats_roundsviewfinish.nine_view_f AS stats_roundsviewfinish_nine_view_f,
       stats_finishes.one_f AS stats_finishes_one_f,
       stats_finishes.two_f AS stats_finishes_two_f,
       stats_finishes.three_f AS stats_finishes_three_f,
       stats_finishes.four_f AS stats_finishes_four_f,
       stats_finishes.five_f AS stats_finishes_five_f,
       stats_finishes.six_f AS stats_finishes_six_f,
       stats_finishes.seven_f AS stats_finishes_seven_f,
       stats_finishes.eight_f AS stats_finishes_eight_f,
       stats_finishes.nine_f AS stats_finishes_nine_f,
       stats_score.first_score AS stats_score_first_score,
       stats_score.second_score AS stats_score_second_score,
       stats_score.is_rusk AS stats_score_is_rusk,
       stats_roundstime.first_t AS stats_roundstime_first_t,
       stats_roundstime.second_t AS stats_roundstime_second_t,
       stats_roundstime.third_t AS stats_roundstime_third_t,
       stats_roundstime.fourth_t AS stats_roundstime_fourth_t,
       stats_roundstime.fifth_t AS stats_roundstime_fifth_t,
       stats_roundstime.sixth_t AS stats_roundstime_sixth_t,
       stats_roundstime.seventh_t AS stats_roundstime_seventh_t,
       stats_roundstime.eighth_t AS stats_roundstime_eighth_t,
       stats_roundstime.ninth_t AS stats_roundstime_ninth_t,
       stats_roundtime.min_time AS stats_roundtime_min_time,
       stats_roundtime.mean_time AS stats_roundtime_mean_time,
       stats_roundtime.max_time AS stats_roundtime_max_time,
       stats_timecoef.min_coef_less AS stats_timecoef_min_coef_less,
       stats_timecoef.mean_coef_less AS stats_timecoef_mean_coef_less,
       stats_timecoef.max_coef_less AS stats_timecoef_max_coef_less,
       stats_timecoef.min_coef_more AS stats_timecoef_min_coef_more,
       stats_timecoef.mean_coef_more AS stats_timecoef_mean_coef_more,
       stats_timecoef.max_coef_more AS stats_timecoef_max_coef_more,
       stats_totals.five_total_more AS stats_totals_five_total_more,
       stats_totals.five_total_less AS stats_totals_five_total_less,
       stats_totals.six_total_more AS stats_totals_six_total_more,
       stats_totals.six_total_less AS stats_totals_six_total_less,
       stats_totals.seven_total_more AS stats_totals_seven_total_more,
       stats_totals.seven_total_less AS stats_totals_seven_total_less,
       stats_totals.eight_total_more AS stats_totals_eight_total_more,
       stats_totals.eight_total_less AS stats_totals_eight_total_less
FROM stats_game
JOIN stats_fighters ON stats_game.id = stats_fighters.game_id
JOIN stats_timestamp ON stats_game.id = stats_timestamp.game_id
JOIN stats_coefs ON stats_game.id = stats_coefs.game_id
JOIN stats_rounds ON stats_game.id = stats_rounds.game_id
JOIN stats_roundsview ON stats_game.id = stats_roundsview.game_id
JOIN stats_roundsviewfinish ON stats_game.id = stats_roundsviewfinish.game_id
JOIN stats_finishes ON stats_game.id = stats_finishes.game_id
JOIN stats_score ON stats_game.id = stats_score.game_id
JOIN stats_roundstime ON stats_game.id = stats_roundstime.game_id
JOIN stats_roundtime ON stats_game.id = stats_roundtime.game_id
JOIN stats_timecoef ON stats_game.id = stats_timecoef.game_id
JOIN stats_totals ON stats_game.id = stats_totals.game_id
ORDER BY stats_game.id DESC LIMIT 200
```

This is explain results:

```
 Limit  (cost=3.71..141.01 rows=200 width=413) (actual time=0.263..4.807 rows=200 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=608
  ->  Merge Join  (cost=3.71..7140.27 rows=10395 width=413) (actual time=0.262..4.754 rows=200 loops=1)
        Merge Cond: (stats_game.id = stats_score.game_id)
        Buffers: shared hit=608
        ->  Merge Join  (cost=3.42..7228.43 rows=11490 width=448) (actual time=0.245..4.364 rows=200 loops=1)
              Merge Cond: (stats_game.id = stats_totals.game_id)
              Buffers: shared hit=572
              ->  Merge Join  (cost=3.14..7202.47 rows=12700 width=380) (actual time=0.230..3.939 rows=200 loops=1)
                    Merge Cond: (stats_game.id = stats_timecoef.game_id)
                    Buffers: shared hit=500
                    ->  Merge Join  (cost=2.85..6409.88 rows=12700 width=328) (actual time=0.215..3.520 rows=200 loops=1)
                          Merge Cond: (stats_game.id = stats_roundtime.game_id)
                          Buffers: shared hit=421
                          ->  Merge Join  (cost=2.57..5665.95 rows=12700 width=300) (actual time=0.199..3.109 rows=200 loops=1)
                                Merge Cond: (stats_game.id = stats_roundstime.game_id)
                                Buffers: shared hit=347
                                ->  Merge Join  (cost=2.28..4906.03 rows=12700 width=260) (actual time=0.181..2.714 rows=200 loops=1)
                                      Merge Cond: (stats_game.id = stats_roundsview.game_id)
                                      Buffers: shared hit=318
                                      ->  Merge Join  (cost=2.00..4680.43 rows=14037 width=233) (actual time=0.154..2.256 rows=200 loops=1)
                                            Merge Cond: (stats_game.id = stats_roundsviewfinish.game_id)
                                            Buffers: shared hit=251
                                            ->  Merge Join  (cost=1.71..4384.11 rows=15515 width=190) (actual time=0.130..1.861 rows=200 loops=1)
                                                  Merge Cond: (stats_game.id = stats_finishes.game_id)
                                                  Buffers: shared hit=222
                                                  ->  Merge Join  (cost=1.43..3620.00 rows=15515 width=168) (actual time=0.116..1.447 rows=200 loops=1)
                                                        Merge Cond: (stats_game.id = stats_rounds.game_id)
                                                        Buffers: shared hit=152
                                                        ->  Merge Join  (cost=1.14..2824.88 rows=15515 width=128) (actual time=0.097..1.101 rows=200 loops=1)
                                                              Merge Cond: (stats_game.id = stats_coefs.game_id)
                                                              Buffers: shared hit=123
                                                              ->  Merge Join  (cost=0.86..1967.77 rows=15515 width=60) (actual time=0.069..0.747 rows=200 loops=1)
                                                                    Merge Cond: (stats_game.id = stats_timestamp.game_id)
                                                                    Buffers: shared hit=74
                                                                    ->  Merge Join  (cost=0.57..1203.66 rows=15515 width=40) (actual time=0.043..0.434 rows=200 loops=1)
                                                                          Merge Cond: (stats_game.id = stats_fighters.game_id)
                                                                          Buffers: shared hit=38
                                                                          ->  Index Only Scan Backward using stats_game_pkey on stats_game  (cost=0.29..413.33 rows=15536 width=4) (actual time=0.025..0.090 rows=200 loops=1)
                                                                                Heap Fetches: 0
                                                                                Buffers: shared hit=4
                                                                          ->  Index Scan Backward using stats_fighters_game_id_5873ae20 on stats_fighters  (cost=0.29..557.56 rows=15515 width=36) (actual time=0.013..0.148 rows=200 loops=1)
                                                                                Buffers: shared hit=34
                                                                    ->  Index Scan Backward using stats_timestamp_game_id_7cba64ec on stats_timestamp  (cost=0.29..531.34 rows=15536 width=20) (actual time=0.023..0.133 rows=200 loops=1)
                                                                          Buffers: shared hit=36
                                                              ->  Index Scan Backward using stats_coefs_game_id_4945e660 on stats_coefs  (cost=0.29..624.33 rows=15536 width=68) (actual time=0.026..0.144 rows=200 loops=1)
                                                                    Buffers: shared hit=49
                                                        ->  Index Scan Backward using stats_rounds_game_id_3021918d on stats_rounds  (cost=0.29..562.33 rows=15536 width=40) (actual time=0.017..0.125 rows=200 loops=1)
                                                              Buffers: shared hit=29
                                                  ->  Index Scan Backward using stats_finishes_game_id_2cae9f9f on stats_finishes  (cost=0.29..531.34 rows=15536 width=22) (actual time=0.011..0.147 rows=200 loops=1)
                                                        Buffers: shared hit=70
                                            ->  Index Scan Backward using stats_roundsviewfinish_game_id_4613fecf on stats_roundsviewfinish  (cost=0.29..523.43 rows=14056 width=43) (actual time=0.020..0.123 rows=200 loops=1)
                                                  Buffers: shared hit=29
                                      ->  Index Scan Backward using stats_roundsview_game_id_5e0e170b on stats_roundsview  (cost=0.29..499.15 rows=14056 width=27) (actual time=0.023..0.154 rows=200 loops=1)
                                            Buffers: shared hit=67
                                ->  Index Scan Backward using stats_roundstime_game_id_503d284c on stats_roundstime  (cost=0.29..562.34 rows=15536 width=40) (actual time=0.015..0.125 rows=200 loops=1)
                                      Buffers: shared hit=29
                          ->  Index Scan Backward using stats_roundtime_game_id_7bb54c53 on stats_roundtime  (cost=0.29..546.34 rows=15536 width=28) (actual time=0.012..0.140 rows=200 loops=1)
                                Buffers: shared hit=74
                    ->  Index Scan Backward using stats_timecoef_game_id_cee96f92 on stats_timecoef  (cost=0.29..595.00 rows=15536 width=52) (actual time=0.010..0.132 rows=200 loops=1)
                          Buffers: shared hit=79
              ->  Index Scan Backward using stats_totals_game_id_dc1ed7ed on stats_totals  (cost=0.29..566.14 rows=14056 width=68) (actual time=0.011..0.127 rows=200 loops=1)
                    Buffers: shared hit=72
        ->  Index Scan Backward using stats_score_game_id_a4e3e3f5 on stats_score  (cost=0.29..468.14 rows=14056 width=13) (actual time=0.012..0.117 rows=200 loops=1)
              Buffers: shared hit=36
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=786
Planning Time: 135.963 ms
Execution Time: 5.172 ms
```

This is my indexes:

```
 schemaname |       tablename        |                indexname                | tablespace |                                                  indexdef
------------+------------------------+-----------------------------------------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 public     | stats_coefs            | stats_coefs_pkey                        |            | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX stats_coefs_pkey ON public.stats_coefs USING btree (id)
 public     | stats_fighters         | stats_fighters_pkey                     |            | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX stats_fighters_pkey ON public.stats_fighters USING btree (id)
 public     | stats_finishes         | stats_finishes_pkey                     |            | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX stats_finishes_pkey ON public.stats_finishes USING btree (id)
 public     | stats_game             | stats_game_pkey                         |            | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX stats_game_pkey ON public.stats_game USING btree (id)
 public     | stats_rounds           | stats_rounds_pkey                       |            | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX stats_rounds_pkey ON public.stats_rounds USING btree (id)
 public     | stats_roundstime       | stats_roundstime_pkey                   |            | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX stats_roundstime_pkey ON public.stats_roundstime USING btree (id)
 public     | stats_roundsview       | stats_roundsview_pkey                   |            | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX stats_roundsview_pkey ON public.stats_roundsview USING btree (id)
 public     | stats_roundsviewfinish | stats_roundsviewfinish_pkey             |            | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX stats_roundsviewfinish_pkey ON public.stats_roundsviewfinish USING btree (id)
 public     | stats_roundtime        | stats_roundtime_pkey                    |            | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX stats_roundtime_pkey ON public.stats_roundtime USING btree (id)
 public     | stats_score            | stats_score_pkey                        |            | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX stats_score_pkey ON public.stats_score USING btree (id)
 public     | stats_timecoef         | stats_timecoef_pkey                     |            | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX stats_timecoef_pkey ON public.stats_timecoef USING btree (id)
 public     | stats_timestamp        | stats_timestamp_pkey                    |            | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX stats_timestamp_pkey ON public.stats_timestamp USING btree (id)
 public     | stats_totals           | stats_totals_pkey                       |            | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX stats_totals_pkey ON public.stats_totals USING btree (id)
 public     | stats_coefs            | stats_coefs_game_id_4945e660            |            | CREATE INDEX stats_coefs_game_id_4945e660 ON public.stats_coefs USING btree (game_id)
 public     | stats_fighters         | stats_fighters_game_id_5873ae20         |            | CREATE INDEX stats_fighters_game_id_5873ae20 ON public.stats_fighters USING btree (game_id)
 public     | stats_finishes         | stats_finishes_game_id_2cae9f9f         |            | CREATE INDEX stats_finishes_game_id_2cae9f9f ON public.stats_finishes USING btree (game_id)
 public     | stats_rounds           | stats_rounds_game_id_3021918d           |            | CREATE INDEX stats_rounds_game_id_3021918d ON public.stats_rounds USING btree (game_id)
 public     | stats_roundstime       | stats_roundstime_game_id_503d284c       |            | CREATE INDEX stats_roundstime_game_id_503d284c ON public.stats_roundstime USING btree (game_id)
 public     | stats_roundsview       | stats_roundsview_game_id_5e0e170b       |            | CREATE INDEX stats_roundsview_game_id_5e0e170b ON public.stats_roundsview USING btree (game_id)
 public     | stats_roundsviewfinish | stats_roundsviewfinish_game_id_4613fecf |            | CREATE INDEX stats_roundsviewfinish_game_id_4613fecf ON public.stats_roundsviewfinish USING btree (game_id)
 public     | stats_roundtime        | stats_roundtime_game_id_7bb54c53        |            | CREATE INDEX stats_roundtime_game_id_7bb54c53 ON public.stats_roundtime USING btree (game_id)
 public     | stats_score            | stats_score_game_id_a4e3e3f5            |            | CREATE INDEX stats_score_game_id_a4e3e3f5 ON public.stats_score USING btree (game_id)
 public     | stats_timecoef         | stats_timecoef_game_id_cee96f92         |            | CREATE INDEX stats_timecoef_game_id_cee96f92 ON public.stats_timecoef USING btree (game_id)
 public     | stats_timestamp        | stats_timestamp_game_id_7cba64ec        |            | CREATE INDEX stats_timestamp_game_id_7cba64ec ON public.stats_timestamp USING btree (game_id)
 public     | stats_totals           | stats_totals_game_id_dc1ed7ed           |            | CREATE INDEX stats_totals_game_id_dc1ed7ed ON public.stats_totals USING btree (game_id)
```

I'm a noob in optimizing queries and don't really understand how to read this EXPLAIN statement.

Is there any way to improve the speed of this query? It usually takes around 500ms which is huge. I wonder if there could be used some simple optimizations, but also would like to know if there is a way to create materialize view and trigger, or it's not worth it?

Comment: Please show the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`, not jus the EXPLAIN.  That way we can see how many rows it actually found at each node, as well as how many it expected to find, and how long it actually took.

Comment: @jjanes Didn't know about this. Done.

Answer (score 0):

Your execution time is one hundredth of your complained about time.  However, your planning time at 136ms is quite long (but still only a third of your complained time).  Is this one planning/execution you show just unusually fast, or do you think the times shown here are a fair representation of the typical case?

If you run this query a lot (and why else would you care if takes 500 ms?), then you could prepare the query, so that it would not need to be planned for each execution.  The details of doing this would depend on your client language and connection library.